# How to find element in page-object gem with custom parameter?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, page-object-gem

I use page-object gem with RSpec and I want to create an element with a custom parameter like

```
link(:derect_link, text: "#{custom_text}"
```

Because I want to get the link to text and this text was changed every time when I starting the test.

How can I use it in spec scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accessor methods do not support custom parameters at run time. You will have to manually create the methods for the link. The equivalent of the methods created by the link accessor would be:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  def derect_link_element(text)
    link_element(text: text)
  end

  def derect_link(text)
    derect_link_element(text).click
  end

  def derect_link?(text)
    derect_link_element(text).exists?
  end
end
```

This would be used like the standard methods, except that you would specify the text of the link:

```
# Click the link
page.derect_link('custom_text')

# Check if the link exists
page.derect_link?('custom_text')

# Get the link element to perform other actions (eg inspect attribute values)
link = page.derect_link_element('custom_text')
link.attribute('href')
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'link_element' for #<Watir::Browser:0x..fd1e305c5547af8de closed=true>`

I got this error

Comment: Sorry, the nested element methods should not be called against `browser`. The example has been corrected.